# How to get a select statement in SQL Server's store procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a store procedure that execute an "insert into" and then a "select". I have used all fetch to get the select's value, but It doesn't work. Please help

This is an example of my code.

SQL SERVER

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROCEDURE
@sample [nvarchar](40)
AS
INSERT INTO SAMPLE
           ([sampleNumber])
     VALUES
           (@sample)
SELECT 'whatever' as texto;
```

PHP

```
----------connection-----------
...
$query="EXEC [SAMPLE_PROCEDURE] ?";
$execQuery=$connection->prepare($query);
$execQuery->bindValue(1, '1');         
$execQuery->execute();
return $result=$execQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//return $ejecutarQuery->fetch();
//return $ejecutarQuery->fetchColumn();
//return $ejecutarQuery->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in your proc

Comment: Hi, thanks to comment. I have recently added it, but It ($execQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) still returns me an empty array (array(0){}) :c

Comment: Does the stored procedure run ad-hoc? Do you have any unit tests to verify your procedure works?

Comment: Any chance you got an error when recently adding SET NOCOUNT ON? e.g.: `Msg 2714 Level 16 State 3 Line 1 There is already an object named 'SAMPLE_PROCEDURE' in the database.` Have you viewed the current source of the stored procedure using SSMS to verify it contains what you think it should?

Comment: Thanks to comment. I have specified my doubt below. I would be really thankful if you may help me